# Appending several times

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code that is appended several times to my page:

```
<li>
  <div class="view">
         <i class="up"></i>
         <div class="score"><p>0</p></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I want to change the score from 0 to 1 when "up" is clicked for only the view that contains the "up" I clicked on.

Since this is an appended div, I can't use `$('.up').click(...`

However, if I use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.up', function(){ 
     $('.score').html("<p>1</p>");
});
```

Then that changes the score for all my views, instead of just the one that I clicked on.

Normally I would use `$(this).html()`.... but since I need the `$(document).on()` then that doesn't work.

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this`, which refers to element which invoked the event handler. There are different ways to traverse to the element, like `.next()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.up', function(){ 
     $(this).next('.score').find('p').html("1");
});
```

*OR*

```
$(document).on('click', '.up', function(){ 
     $(this).closest('.view').find('.score p').html("1");
});
```

Comment: @Nick if it worked for you, you should award Satpal with the correct answer.